# Creating map with empty values

Tags: go

I need to use a `map` for keys only, I don't need to store values. So I declared a map like this:

```
modified_accounts:=make(map[int]struct{})
```

The idea is to use empty struct because it doesn't consume storage.

However, when I tried to add an entry to the map,

```
modified_accounts[2332]=struct{}
```

I got a compile error:

```
./blockchain.go:291:28: type struct {} is not an expression
```

How do I add an empty key and no value to the map ?

Comment: To get to the heart of the issue: `struct{}` is a type. `struct{}{}` is an instance of that type.

Comment: Why do you even use a map, then, and not a slice?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, maps guarantee duplicated entries are removed, slice will not do this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton `O(1)` key-lookup instead of `O(n)` or `O(log n)` if sorted - i.e. when using it as a set datatype.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do it declaring a empty variable

```
var Empty struct{}

func foo() {
    modified_accounts := make(map[int]struct{})
    modified_accounts[2332] = Empty
    fmt.Println(modified_accounts)
}
```

Or creating a new struct every time

```
func bar() {
    modified_accounts := make(map[int]struct{})
    modified_accounts[2332] = struct{}{}
    fmt.Println(modified_accounts)
}
```

To create a empty `struct` you should use `struct{}{}`

Answer (score 9):

The error is exactly what you see in the below line :

> ./blockchain.go:291:28: type struct {} is not an expression

An expression is something that `evaluates to something` (something that has a value), `struct{}` is a type, and your statement is trying to assign a type(right) to a map's key's value, a variable(left)

What you need is to create a variable of this type, and assign that variable to the map's key as a value.

Either by using :

```
var x struct{}
modified_accounts[2332] = x
```

or

```
modified_accounts[2332] = struct{}{}
```

In either of the above way, you are creating a value of type `struct{}`, and assigning that value to the map's key.